# An expandable and collapsible tree

Tags: javascript, json, list, tree

Please help me how to create an expandable and collapsible tree with JavaScript with JSON feed data shown in the following format.Need some help with this problem.

```
var dataSource = ({
            "Items": ({
                "Pen": ({}),
                "Pencil": ({
                    "Natraj": "Natraj Pencil",
                    "Afsara": "Afsara Pencil",
                    "Erason": "natraj Erason"
                }),

                "Book": ({
                    "Novel": "ShakeSpear Novel"
                }),
            })
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xWkj7/). I would recommend creating objects in javascript and then converting those objects/arrays to JSON if needed...

```
var dataSource = [];

dataSource.push({
    Items: [{
        Pen: [],
        Pencil: [
            {Natraj: "Natraj Pencil"},
            {Afsara: "Afsara Pencil"},
            {Efason: "natraj Erason"}
        ],
        Book: [
            {Novel: "Shakespear Novel"}
        ]
    }]
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSource));
```

Comment: but how should i make it expandable and collapsible operation by a click so that it will act as a folder tree?

Comment: Unless you plan to write the entire tree view yourself. I would recommend looking into something like a jQuery plugin such as jsTree (http://www.jstree.com/demo) which can interpret json into a tree format.

Comment: okay can suggest me the operation of how to perform expandable and collapsible operation with JavaScript not Jquery as in Jquery it is very simple but not able to figure it out in JavaScript.It would be really appreciable getting the solution for this question

Comment: i am really sorry that i couldn't explain you properly,how can i perform  expandable operation by a click on "Pencil" and if i again click on "pencil" it will close ...see the dataSource JSON